# JSF lifecycle, how can response complete happen in the middle of the life cycle?

Tags: jsf

I am going through the article on [JSF LifeCycles](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSFIntro10.html). I have the following doubt.

- In many phases, the Response Complete is happening. How it is happening in
  the middle of the life cycle. Can anyone explain it in detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the [JSF 2.0 spec](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314):

> The `responseComplete()` method, on the other hand, signals the JSF implementation that the HTTP response for this request has been completed by some means other than rendering the component tree, and that the request processing lifecycle for this request should be terminated when the current phase is complete. For example, an event listener that decided an HTTP redirect was required would perform the appropriate actions on the response object (i.e. calling `ExternalContext.redirect()`) and then call this method.

Calling [ExternalContext.redirect(String)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) in a JSF servlet application causes a [302 response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.3.3) to be sent to the browser via the [underlying API](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29). In this case, it would be an error (or at least futile) to emit data in the response body, so `ExternalContext.redirect(String)` calls `responseComplete()`.

Comment: Indeed, but only when it's done by `ExternalContext#redirect()`. Grabbing `HttpServletResponse` from under JSF's covers and calling `sendRedirect()` on it won't do that.

Comment: @BalusC - you're right; I'm making the assumption callers are sticking to the JSF API

Comment: Still I am not clear with your answer.Do you meant to say that when ever there is redirect to another application outside JSF context is response complete?

Comment: @BalusC: That's great: with ExternalContext.responseComplete() the JSF-life-cycle seems to be interrupted and left. So I can write my own data to the HttpServletResponse before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how it is happening I guess they do multi threading.

In case you are asking why it is happening, it is for the ajax requests or for repsonses that have to be submitted immediately

Comment: I could not understand your answer.